# Python fastest way to find if a tuple or its reverse is in a list?

Tags: python

I have a nested list of tuples that acts as a cache, for a script to decide which Queue to put packet data into, for its respective multiprocessing.Process() to process.

For example:

```
queueCache = [[('100.0.1.19035291111.0.0.255321TCP', '111.0.0.255321100.0.1.19035291TCP'), ('100.0.0.41842111.0.0.280TCP', '111.0.0.280100.0.0.41842TCP')], [('100.0.1.18722506111.0.0.345968TCP', '111.0.0.345968100.0.1.18722506TCP'), ('100.0.0.11710499111.0.0.328881TCP', '111.0.0.328881100.0.0.11710499TCP')], [('100.0.0.14950710111.0.0.339767TCP', '111.0.0.339767100.0.0.14950710TCP'), ('100.0.0.8663063111.0.0.280TCP', '111.0.0.280100.0.0.8663063TCP')]]
```

If the tuple `('100.0.1.19035291111.0.0.255321TCP', '111.0.0.255321100.0.1.19035291TCP')` or `('111.0.0.255321100.0.1.19035291TCP', '100.0.1.19035291111.0.0.255321TCP')` (the reverse) is given, 0 should be returned, indicating index 0, and that its respective data should be put into the "first" queue. If it is not in the cache, it will be sent to the queue with the shortest queue record. (This is irrelevant to the question but relevant to my example code below).

This is what I have so far:

```py
for i in range(len(queueCache)):
    if any(x in queueCache[i] for x in ((fwd_tup, bwd_tup), (bwd_tup, fwd_tup))):
        index = i
        break
else:
    index = queueCache.index(min(queueCache, key=len))
    queueCache[index].append((fwd_tup, bwd_tup))
```

Running some benchmarks with much greater sample data, if the tuple is at the end of the cache (which should be common since newest tuples are appended), 100,000 runs takes about 9.5 seconds, which is probably more than it should.

```
# using timeit:
print("Normal search, target at start: %f" % timeit(f"search('{fwd_tup1}', '{bwd_tup1}')", "from __main__ import search", number=100000))
print("Normal search, target at middle: %f" % timeit(f"search('{fwd_tup2}', '{bwd_tup2}')", "from __main__ import search", number=100000))
print("Normal search, target at end: %f" % timeit(f"search('{fwd_tup3}', '{bwd_tup3}')", "from __main__ import search", number=100000))
```

`Normal search, target at start: 0.155531`

`Normal search, target in the middle: 4.507907`

`Normal search, target at end: 9.470369`

Perhaps there is a way to start the search from the end?

Note: The script deletes records when possible, but for specific reasons most records need to stay in the cache, thus it ends up being significantly sized.

Edit: Using a dictionary yields much greater results, thank you to @SilvioMayolo and @MisterMiyagi for the help.

Transforming the sample data to a dictionary (just for this specific testing purpose):

```
d = {}
for i, list in enumerate(queueCache):
    for tup in list:
        d[tup] = i
```

Then simply:

```
def dictSearch(fwd_tup, bwd_tup):
    global d
    d[(fwd_tup, bwd_tup)]
```

Results:

```
Dictionary search, target at start: 0.044860

Dictionary search, target at middle: 0.042514

Dictionary search, target at end: 0.044760
```

Amazing. Faster than the list search where the target is at the start!

Comment: Some sort of key-based lookup like a dictionary or set (with the tuple and its reverse added at the same time) would be beneficial to your search time. But if this is truly running at scales of hundreds of thousands of entries and things are constantly being added, then you'll save yourself tons of trouble if you let a database manage this for you, rather than dealing with storage at the application level.

Comment: A list is not suitable for item lookup. Why are you explicitly looking for a fast way to do something that will always be slow? Focusing on the actual task and choosing appropriate data structures seems more productive.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi would a dictionary like what @SilvioMayolo had mentioned be a better choice? Or are there better alternatives? What would an example of using a dictionary in this context be? Maybe `{('100.0.1.19035291111.0.0.255321TCP', '111.0.0.255321100.0.1.19035291TCP'): 0}`?

Comment: Either way, we cannot really tell you how to do something fast when we don't exactly know what that something is. How many items are there - tens, thousands, more? How often are items evicted from the cache? How many cache misses do you expect on average? What is the relation between and inside items, i.e. is it actually necessary to find the precise item or just a stem? Can the list be sorted or otherwise prepared for faster search?

Comment: Yes, a `dict` is Python's default mapping/lookup type. Your example looks about right, though I would directly point at the queue, not some index.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The dictionary ended being much faster than even the list search where the target is at the start.